# How to add a custom button on CRM subgrid?

Tags: dynamics-crm, subgrid, crm-ribbon-workbench

I have two entities in my Dynamics CRM solution. Both are related to each other.
Product -> configurations

Each product can have multiple configurations. I have added a subgrid on product screen.

[image]

I need to call a custom html webresource to be able to create configuration records.

How to add a custom button to the subgrid? OR how to customize existing (+) button to open an html webresource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the entity to a solution & take a backup
2. Open the solution in Ribbon workbench
3. Start customizing the subgrid ribbon (ignore other two - Main grid & Form), right click the OOB button & hide it (this is also a backup)
4. Add a new button & custom javascript action command ([follow this](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/briteglobalsolutions/archive/2017/10/22/creating-a-ribbon-button-using-ribbon-workbench-to-call-a-javascript-action))
5. Open your custom HTML webresource using [openWebResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openwebresource#syntax) method in javascript function