# How to pass parameters to a form using grid's plus button?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I open a new form using the **+** button of a grid, how do I pass parameters to the new form I open without using the

```
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm
```

or can I use `Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm` in that case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about OOB `Add New (+)` button, then you have to do one of these options:

Either customize that button/command to hook your own javascript action and pass the parameter.

Or hide the OOB button for future backup usage and add a custom button to invoke custom javascript action and pass parameter.

On both cases, custom javascript action will have a library and a method. In that custom javascript method, you can use `Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm` and pass with needed parameters.

[Refer this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53816177/7920473)

```
function invokeCustomAddbutton(){
    var parameters = {};
    parameters["formid"] = "b053a39a-041a-4356-acef-ddf00182762b";
    parameters["name"] = "Test";
    parameters["telephone1"] = "(425) 555-1234";
    Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("account", null, parameters);
}
```

You can keep the above method in a js library, and map that in Ribbon command.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/jj602956(v=crm.8)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#openentityform)

Comment: If we're talking about OOB 'Add New' why not just use the mappings from the relationship?

Comment: @JustDoIt I assumed they are not just form values from existing available mapping fields.. :)

Comment: Fair enough hehe.